# Unable to disable apple music

Tags: music, iphone, crash, apple-music

I found a setting to show or hide apple music (`Music -> Show Apple Music`). I turned it off, but now when I go to the music app it shows me the apple music ad with no buttons for ~2 seconds and then the app crashes. Restarting/Resetting the iPhone has no effect. When I re-enable apple music the app works again. I have iOS 9.3.5 on my iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely a software issue – since iOS 9.3.5 is a relatively recent update, it is bound to have some bugs. If that's the case, you'll need to wait it out until the next update, which will probably be iOS 10 in September.

Comment: If that is true, that stinks because 9.3.5 is the last version for my phone :(